# Is n$^{99}+n^{98}$ $\in$ O($n^{99}$)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

If so, are there witnesses that prove this true? My initial thought is no, considering that the limit of $n^{99}+{n^{98} \over n^{99}}$ as n approaches $\infty$ is 1, however my professor had mentioned this is not sufficient to prove big O relation.

Comment: $1+\frac23 \ne \frac{1+2}3$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, consider that $n^{99} + n^{98} < 2 \cdot n^{99}$ for $n \ge 2$.  Also I don't think there is anything wrong with your method of proof (except that you're getting the wrong conclusion somehow).

Comment: I believe I forgot what my limit signifies- if the limit is 1 then it is big theta, which would mean it is big O.